# NullReferenceException:Object reference not set to an instance of an object. SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-config

i have issue to run this asp.net script on my server,

I get this error :

Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Gilass.ApplicationBase.SQLDataProvider.Select(String srcTable, String whereClause, String orderClause, Boolean noSecure) +455
   Gilass.ApplicationBase.SQLDataProvider.Select(String srcTable, String whereClause, String orderClause) +19
   Gilass.ApplicationBase.HostSettings.Get(String settingName) +79
   GilassSocial.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +418

[HttpException (`0x80004005`): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) `+3985477`
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +191
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +325
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +407
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +375

[HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11524352
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4782309

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

i think i need change something in web.config , this is my web.config information :

```
<Gilass>
    <data defaultProvider="WIN-AK7E554L8NA\SQLEXPRESS">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="WIN-AK7E554L8NA\SQLEXPRESS" type="WIN-AK7E554L8NA\SQLEXPRESS" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=db_name;uid=gilass;pwd=****;" providerPath="~\" objectQualifier="" databaseOwner="gilass" upgradeConnectionString="" />
      </providers>
    </data>
  </Gilass>
```

Any advice ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use more than one forms? Like one in master, one in aspx or somewhere else?

Comment: Nop , but , i think it was a mistake on web.config file , can you check this file ? also i can provide access from server to check it . thanks